# Vega nested group not correctly filtering global dataset

Tags: vega

This question refers to the code that you can play around with in the [Vega editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykSArJQBWENgDsQAGhAB3GgBN6aAIwAmAAwaZ8GmSxoAbFpk4kChTXFk02kAqSYUqANqhxSBHDQhMcCJgA+g5O0iDESAA2DP5obiBWCnAAHrYyEdHe6IkpAAQauRkxIAC+UqA5qagq6VHF2eJJybkqhXXeJQC6Ze6eWSBkAE5sDDjBjii1mRBxoEkQNINwCoGVtj32-ovLq40pql1dMsiDANYzrqCYAJ44-UMjOGEAZsMIaHMTPg+j46Fl9i+lxAHi8PggzB+YxCk3C7QubiOvkGSHEEGebEG72BNzuPgxWIYkVhSAumwWSxWaxkKRwgx8ZiW4kwlHm2ype1SG1x-QJCCJJLJyUCODYMxpyTpDKQTJZbMpuyauQAVC0tKVup1jjLzrNfLd7sNRi83h9AaF0BCmFC-igATC9aD+hA4JE4FA-CsHTIxAxBlB+n4ArawpgUWi+XqefiaJE-PSJVL0CEGAhWJzcgBeTO5RlwZmsrYKtaHLUgE66nEGnx+ZKYE1sbGfC0gF1uj07B0A-NQNhJM35+Nm2v11CgZ40V0KHxFDoA0YhLKgKrjyeRafoYWimYlXelw5AA), also reproduced below:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega/v5.json",
  "width": 1200,
  "height": 600,
  "padding": 0,

  "data": [
    {
      "name": "test_data",
      "values": [
        {"index": 0, "value": "index 0 value"},
        {"index": 1, "value": "index 1 value"}
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "group_data",
      "values": [
        {"desired_index": 0},
        {"desired_index": 1}
      ]
    }
  ],

  "marks": [
    {
      "type": "group",
      "from": {"data": "group_data"},

      "data": [
        {
          "name": "subgroup_data",
          "values": [
            {}
          ],
          "transform": [
            {
              "type": "formula",
              "as": "desired_index",
              "expr": "parent.desired_index"
            },
            {
              "type": "formula",
              "as": "x_pos",
              "expr": "parent.desired_index * 100"
            }
          ]
        }
      ],

      "marks": [
        { 
          "type": "group",
          "from": {"data": "subgroup_data"},
          "data": [
            {
              "name": "selected_data",
              "source": "test_data",
              "transform": [
                {
                  "type": "filter",
                  "expr": "datum.index == parent.desired_index"
                }
              ]
            }
          ],
          "marks": [
            {
              "type": "text",
              "from": {"data": "selected_data"},
              "encode": {
                "enter": {
                  "text": {"field": "value"}
                },
                "update": {
                  "x": {"field": "x_pos"}
                }
              }
            }           
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

This is a contrived example that reproduces some behavior I don't fully understand on a larger problem.

Essentially, I have a global array of data called `test_data`. I then want to do a doubly nested group mark. The first level of grouping just iterates over a `group_data` array, which specifies which index in `test_data` we are ultimately going to use for each instantiation. Each group instance should then provide a data array `subgroup_data` which "passes through" the desired index and a calculated x position. Of course, it doesn't make sense to nest here with only one entry in `subgroup_data` but this is just a MRE.

Now the inner group mark should use the provided `desired_index` to filter the global `test_data` array, and render the resulting `value` field as text. I am expecting the output:
`index 0 value       index 1 value`

But running the above just prints out `index 1 value` (which is actually two `index 1 value`'s rendered on top of one another).

I don't quite understand what is going on here. It seems that the `data` field on the parent group isn't being properly scope-restricted somehow. I would appreciate any pointers!

Comment: I don't fully understand your example but the Pancake Spider Chart example on this page has groups nested within groups which I think is what you're trying to do and may help. https://github.com/PBI-David/Deneb-Showcase